# Clearcase - RQMCommandLine Adapter

Tags: clearcase, ibm-rational

How to start a RQM adapter on linux machine? In which directory is start.sh can be found?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [doc mentions](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21474535) that you must be on the be on the machine where Rational Quality Manager is installed. (Windows or Linux machine)

> Before running the Rational Quality Manager Command Line Adapter, please make sure that:
>
> - java.exe is accessible in the path
> - the version of JAVA required is 1.5 or later
> - user ID to log into Rational Quality Manager that has appropriate licenses to login as an adapter

The [README includes](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21474535&aid=1):

```
start.sh -repository https://<rqmserver>:<port>/jazz -user <userid> -password <password> -adapter <adapter> \ 
[-projectArea <project area>] [-sleepTime <sleep time>] \
[-configFile <configuration file>]
```

**Since that adapter is provided as a compressed archive at  `<RQM_INSTALL_DIR>\adapters\RQMCommandLineAdapter.zip`, the `start.sh` will be where you have unzipped that archive.**